# Function that acts on a variable as said variable's attribute

Tags: python

**EDIT**: Figured it out:

```
class i(int):
   def __init__(self, __int: int):
      self.__int = __int
   def __times_two__(self):
      return self.__int * 2

v = i(3)
print(v.__times_two__())
>>> 6
```

Forgive my lack of terminology, not too sure how to word this question (possibly why I've had so much trouble finding an answer). Here's an example of what I would like to do:

```
def times_two(x):
   return x*2

class MyClass:
   _1=1
   _2=2

MyClass._2.times_two()
>>> 4
```

This isn't literally what I want, but I basically want to have a function that can act on a given variable and return the result of an action performed on that variable. This may just not be possible, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In order for `MyClass._2` to have a `.times_two()` method, it would have to be an instance of a class that defines such a method.  It cannot possibly be an `int`, as you currently have it - but it could be a subclass of `int`, so that you could otherwise use it as you would a standard integer.

Comment: The problem is that you need to create an instance of your class to be able to use the class methods. So, you need to do something like this: `myObject = MyClass` `myObject.times_two(myObject._2)`

Comment: How might one go about do this? I got the class method to show up
class _int(int):
   @classmethod
   def __times_two__(self):
      return self * 2
v: _int = 3

But even though __times_two__ shows up, it doesn't work because 3 is still an int.

Comment: @jasonharper Just got it figured out with a bit of tinkering (edited original post). Thanks for the idea!

Comment: That's not quite what I was suggesting - your objects have *two* values, the inherent value of the `int` (set via the inherited `__new__()`), and the value assigned to your `__int` attribute.  You don't need the second one - get rid of `__init__()` completely, have your `times_two()` simply return `self * 2`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a dictionary instead of a class, and feed into your function whatever is inside it, for example:

```
>>> def times_two(x):
        return x*2

>>> data={"_1":1, "_2":2}
>>> times_two(data["_1"])
2
>>> times_two(data["_2"])
4
>>>
```

---

about your peculiar solution, if you in turn want that the result to also have this extra method, you need to make sure is an instance of your personalize class

```
>>> class int2(int):
        def times_two(self):
            return type(self)(self*2) #with this the result is an int2

    
>>> i=int2(1)
>>> i
1
>>> i.times_two().times_two()
4
>>> type(_)
<class '__main__.int2'>
>>>
```

Comment: I think I got it figured out :)

Comment: @TannerCorcoran I included some sugestion for your solution